# How can I create a new customer in Netsuite with a default billing/shipping address?

Tags: php, api, netsuite

I am trying to using Netsuite's PHPtoolkip_v2010.php to add new customer records and define their default shipping and billing addresses.  But I'm having trouble wading through the documentation.

Here's how I create the customer now:

```
$customer_data = array(
    'firstName'=>$billing_address['first_name'],
    'lastName'=>$billing_address['last_name'],
    'email'=>$email,
    'phone'=>$phone,
    'isPerson'=>true
);
if(!empty($billing_address['company'])) $customer_data['companyName'] = $billing_address['company'];

$customer = new nsComplexObject('Customer', $customer_data);
$new_customer = $ns->add($customer);
if($new_customer->isSuccess) {
    $customer_id = $new_customer->recordRef->nsComplexObject_fields['internalId'];
}
```

That successfully creates the customer record and returns the Customer's internalId.

The schema browser lists a field `addressbookList` of type `listRel:CustomerAddressbookList`.  I assume I need to create a list, add the address to the list, then attach the list to the customer record.  But I'm unsure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the 2010 update much, but I have posted on my blog sample code from previous versions of the toolkit.  I assume they should still work.
[Create Netsuite Customer Address Object](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2011/12/create-netsuite-customer-with-addresses/)

Its worth noting that the structure will change if you have multiple addresses vs a single address.  The sample I linked to is for multiple addresses.

Hope this helps.